# Handling eclipse workspaces properly

Tags: eclipse, workspace

Let's say I use Eclipse classic and add the php, python and java functionality. Is it recommended to use a workspace for every language, or is it no problem to have a workspace for them all? Some years ago I read, there would be conflicts, and I want to get my doubts out of my way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have only one workspace for all environment, since it will manage the different perspectives involved with each languages.

That being said, since Eclipse introduced the "switch workspace" feature, you could define several workspaces, but that will close/relaunch your Eclipse.
If you are working closely on sources including all three languages, one workspace is your best choice.